# Pagination fetching rows more than once in search records in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am working on this from quite while, and yet my pagination is although working so far, but looking at it closer it seems that on the last page it's pulling in previous results to fill the page in.

So say I want ten per page  and have fourteen results. The first page has ten results, and so does the second. When it should be the first has **ten** and the second has **four**. It would be fine if it was just repeating one result, but it's irritating to have to scroll through six previous results. Any help would be much appreciated thanks in advance.

**Search result url**

> https://xxxx.xxx/site/search?id=2&query=2+Pc+Meal&page=2

**id=2** is the restaurant ID  & **query** param is for entered search keyword

**controller**

```
 // THIS FUNCTION IS RESPONSIBLE FOR SHOWING SEARCH RESULTS
    function search()
    {
    
        $page_data['restaurant_id']    =  sanitize($_GET['id']);
        $page_data['query']            =  sanitize($_GET['query']);   
        $page_data['page_name']        = 'search/index';
        $page_data['page_title']       = 'Search result';
        
        /**PAGINATION STARTS**/
        $total_rows = $this->menu_model->count_search_menu($page_data['query'], $page_data['restaurant_id']);
        $page_size = 10;
        $pagination_url = site_url('site/search');
        $config = pagintaion($total_rows, $page_size, $pagination_url);
        $current_page = sanitize($this->input->get('page', 0));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page_data['total_rows']  = $total_rows;
        $page_data['search_result'] = $this->menu_model->get_searched_menu_by_name_and_restaurant($page_data['query'], $page_data['restaurant_id'], $page_size ,$current_page);

        $this->load->view(frontend('index'), $page_data);

    }
```

**MODAL**

```
 // COUNT TOTAL ROWS
    public function count_search_menu($query, $restaurant)
    {
        $this->db->where('restaurant_id', $restaurant);
        $this->db->like('name', $query, 'both'); //both = %query%, before = %query, after = query%
        $menu  = $this->db->get($this->table);
        $result = $menu->result();
        $count = count($result);
        return $count;
    }

     // GET MENU BY SEARCH NAME AND RESTAURANT ID
    public function get_searched_menu_by_name_and_restaurant($query, $restaurant, $limit, $start)
    {
        $this->db->where('restaurant_id', $restaurant);
        $this->db->like('name', $query, 'both'); //both = %query%, before = %query, after = query%

        // Executes: SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
        // get([$table = ''[, $limit = NULL[, $offset = NULL]]])
       // $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);

        $menu  = $this->db->get($this->table, $limit, $start);
        return $menu->result();
    }
```

**Visual look example:**

**per page** = 10

**total rows** = 25

[image: same result]

As u can see above, all 3 pages show 10 items, instead it should be show **10 on 1st** page, **10 on 2nd** and **5 on 3rd** page.

Comment: You need to multiply `$current_page` by `$page_size` and use that as the offset.

Comment: what a eye dude! yes exactly! thankyou so much

Comment: Pagination without ordering makes little sense. Will show you random rows of data.